# Bokeh: tooltip not showing values when using a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

A simple bar chart with bokeh and pandas doesn't parse the Column1 values in the tooltip (instead showing ???):

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

my_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Column1": [7,19,16],
        "Column2": ["Age","Age","Notage"]
    }, index = [
        "Row1",
        "Row2",
        "Row3"
    ]
)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("index1", "@Column1")
    ]
)

p = bk.figure(
    tools=[hover],
    x_range=list(my_df.index.values),
)

p.vbar(
    x=list(my_df.index.values),
    width=0.4,
    top=my_df["Column1"]
)

bk.show(p)
```

Why is that and why most examples pass in a `source = ColumnDataSource(my_df)`. Can it be done without ColumnDataSource ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did it like this. If someone has an example without ColumnDataSource please post.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

my_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Column1": [7,19,16],
        "Column2": ["Age","Age","Notage"],
        "Rows": ["Row1", "Row2", "Row3" ]
    }
)
source = bk.ColumnDataSource(my_df)
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("index1", "@Column1")
    ]
)

p = bk.figure(
    tools=[hover],
    x_range=list(my_df["Rows"].values),
)

p.vbar(
    x="Rows",
    width=0.4,
    top="Column1",
source=source
)

bk.show(p)
```

Comment: There is always a `ColumnDataSource`, just sometimes Bokeh will create one for you in simple situations. However, if you want to have a hover tool, it is almost always advised (and often necessary, e.g. if you want to include extra columns) to create the CDS yourself, as you have done here. This way is the correct way to do things.